# How to eliminate dependent inputs?

Tags: data-transformation, assumptions, independence

There are a lot of statistical methods that rely on the assumption of input independence. For example, Naive Bayes text classifiers operate under the assumption that occurrences of different words are conditionally independent given the document class. Another example - HDMR and Sobol variance decomposition seem like very powerful methods to me, but they require this assumption.

But suppose that I have a large dataset where inputs are very much non-independent, and I still want to apply the method. The character of the dependency is implicit: I do not have an explicit model for computing some of the inputs given others.

What are some data transformations that transform a dataset with dependent inputs to a dataset with independent inputs, under some class of input dependency models?

Comment: Principal Components Analysis?

Comment: Yes, that's a great example, for the case when dependencies are only pairwise, linear, and affect only the mean rather than variance. That got me looking at generalizations of PCA, thanks.